# How does Shopify resolve conflicting App Proxy URLs?

Tags: e-commerce, shopify, shopify-app

A [Shopify app proxy](https://help.shopify.com/api/tutorials/application-proxies) is a URL that an app can automatically set up for you.  It is a URL that looks like a store's URL but it is actually proxied to some alternate app URL.

example: `example.myshopify.com/a/test` can be set up by an app to proxy to whatever URL the app wants.

Seen here are some settings from the `partners dashboard`: [image]

**My question:** what happens if two apps set up a proxy at `/a/proxy`, and the user installs both of those apps?  `example.myshopify.com/a/proxy` could then go to one of two different places?

This seems like a disastrous circumstance?  I'm really confused.  What am I missing, here?

Comment: It's a great question. The bind that you get into as a developer here is that you want your links to be unique enough so no conflict arises, but also in plain English for SEO purposes...

Comment: this "feature" is an absolute disaster, apps have no way of knowing what a merchant has set their proxy to or if a number has been appended to the proxy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered the answer to this through some testing.

Shopify resolves the conflicting app proxy by appending a number onto the end of the `Sub path` portion of the most recent app URL.

So, if a user installs app 1 with `Sub path prefix` as `a` and `Sub path` as `test`.
And then user installs app 2 with the same `Sub path prefix` and `Sub path` then app 2 will automatically get a `Sub path` of `test-1`.